# Connector to temporary connect SMD IC?

Tags: integrated-circuit, connector, prototyping

Is there any material/device invented to quickly connect SOIC-14 like integrated circuits to, eg, breadboard? I am aware of adapter boards, but what if I want something without soldering? (I am not speaking of very high frequencies and too complex SMDs)

For example, if I remember correctly, I saw similar technology used for small LCD displays (where some kind of resin and evenly spaced wires provided very fine connection from the board to the LCD), so I guess, this kind of technique is possible. SOIC 14, in this example, would require two such  "wired pillow" connection terminals, which can be mapped to pins and/or wires.

Is there anything like this existing? Or maybe something with similar purpose, but universal enough to be useful with several cases?

[image]

**UPDATE**: There are prototype boards in existence, which make it much easier (and cheaper) to work with SMDs, eg http://www.whitewing.co.uk/protoboard.html . I wish, there were more such boards available for all kinds of SMDs.

**UPDATE2**: Actually, I have found anything I needed here: http://www.proto-advantage.com/store/ It seems, they have adapters for nearly everything. ZIF sockets, proposed in the answer, are also quite convenient in use.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Common practice is to use a ZIF adapter, aka programming socket adapter, test socket, etc, for the relevant IC form factor. For SOIC 16 through 24, for instance, [this adapter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Programming-Socket-Adapter-ZIF-SOIC24-SOP24-/221200837437?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item338098eb3d) (*$13.99 on eBay*) can be used:

[image: ZIF SOIC socket]

Such ZIF sockets exist for several standard SMD IC formats.

---

The resin-like conducting strips used in LCDs are called [elastomeric connectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastomeric_connector), and are available in various pin pitches:

[image: Elastomer]

These can be purchased in long strips and cut up for use on a DIP adapter, but there don't seem to be any such adapters available on the sites I know of.

Comment: Thanks, this is exhaustive answer. I can continue with those key words.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a [ZIF socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_insertion_force), sometimes called a programming adapter. [Example](http://www.elnec.com/products/programming-adapters/?f=DIL14_SOIC14_ZIF_150mil) of a 14 pin SOIC programming adapter.

Comment: Discontinued :-(

Comment: I was providing a hint as to what to look for, not shopping advice, as we are not a shopping advice site.

Comment: Sure. Thanks. I just got an impression, that these sockets are somehow not manufactured any more.